# Bool has no attribute fetchone, even though its a cursor

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, asynchronous, async-await

im getting this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\aver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
   ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
 File "c:\Users\aver\Documents\GitHub\EconomyX\src\cogs\playermeta.py", line 34, in register
   data = await c.fetchone()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'fetchone'
```

this is my code:

```
c = await bot.db.execute("SELECT * FROM e_users WHERE id = ?",(id,))
data = await c.fetchone()
```

i have also tried putting a print statement in between, and it prints out
`<aiosqlite.cursor.Cursor object at 0x06E9EF88>`
So why does it complain its a bool?
My full code can be found here: https://github.com/averwhy/EconomyX
Im using discord.py to store the aiosqlite connection pool in a botvar

Comment: `c` is not a cursor. You are overwriting is one line before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i messed up on my own code, and tried to create a cursor object off of a method i made that returned a list. I've facepalmed incredibly hard
Moral of the story; look at all your code carefully, or have a friend look at it before embarrassing yourself online